# How do you compare a 2d vector of custom objects in C++

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

I created an object called [Perception_Element]

**H FILE**

```
#define PERCEPTION_ELEMENT_H

#include <Root.h>
using namespace Utilities;

namespace Perception {
    namespace Layer {
        namespace Element {
            class Perception_Element {
                public:
                    Perception_Element();

                    Perception_Element(float param_value);

                    void Set_Value(float param_value);

                    float Get_Value();

                    bool operator==(const Perception_Element element);

                    ~Perception_Element();

                private:
                    float value;

            };
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

**CPP**

```
#include <Perception_Element.h>

using namespace Perception::Layer::Element;

Perception_Element::Perception_Element() {}

Perception_Element::Perception_Element(float param_value) {
    this->value = param_value;
}

void Perception_Element::Set_Value(float param_value) {
    this->value = param_value;
}

float Perception_Element::Get_Value() {
    return this->value;
}

bool Perception_Element::operator==(const Perception_Element element) {
    return (this->Get_Value() == element.value);
}


Perception_Element::~Perception_Element() {}
```

And then I created a class that inherits from it called Prediction

**H**

```
#ifndef Prediction_H
#define Prediction_H

#include <Perception_Element.h>

using namespace Utilities;

namespace Perception {

    namespace Layer {
        namespace Element {
            class Prediction : public Perception_Element
            {
            public:
                Prediction();
                Prediction(float param_value);
                ~Prediction();
            };
        }
    }
}
#endif // !Prediction_H
```

**CPP**

```
#include <Prediction.h>

using namespace Perception::Layer::Element;
/// <summary>
/// Instantiate an empty Input for a Neural Node 
/// </summary>
Prediction::Prediction()
{
}

/// <summary>
/// Instantiate an Input for a Neural Node and assigns it a value for input
/// </summary>
/// <param name="param_value">float</param>
Prediction::Prediction(float param_value) : Perception_Element(param_value)
{
}



/// <summary>
/// destructor for input object
/// </summary>
Prediction::~Prediction()
{
}
```

Just for Good measure the function I call is defined here

```
void Layer::Dot_Product(vector<vector<Neural_Node>> param_inputs, vector<vector<Weight>> param_weights) {
    float results = 0;

    // iterate through the inputs rows to get the row index for the inputs and the outputs matrix
    for (int neural_node_row_index = 0; neural_node_row_index < param_inputs.size(); neural_node_row_index++) {
            // iterate through the inputs columns to get the column index for the input and the output matrix
            for (int result_matrix_index = 0; result_matrix_index < param_inputs[neural_node_row_index].size(); result_matrix_index++) {
                // iterate through the inputs columns to get the column index for the output matrix
                for (int neural_node_column_index = 0; neural_node_column_index < param_inputs[neural_node_row_index].size(); neural_node_column_index++) {


                    /*
                      {    INPUT             {     OUTPUT            {        RESULT
                          {1, 2, 3, 4 }          {1, 2, 3, 4 }               {(INROW0, OUTROW0), (INROW0, OUTROW1), (INROW0, OUTROW2)}
                          {1, 2, 3, 4 }          {1, 2, 3, 4 }               {(INROW1, OUTROW0), (INROW1, OUTROW1), (INROW1, OUTROW2)}
                          {1, 2, 3, 4 }          {1, 2, 3, 4 }               {(INROW2, OUTROW0), (INROW2, OUTROW1), (INROW2, OUTROW2)}
                      }                      }                       }
                    */


                results +=
                    param_inputs[neural_node_row_index][neural_node_column_index].Get_Value()
                    *
                    param_weights[neural_node_row_index][neural_node_column_index].Get_Value();
            }
            this->predictions[neural_node_row_index][result_matrix_index].Set_Value(results);
            results = 0;

        }
     }
}
```

And now im writing unit testing and in trying to compare the matrix (2d vector) it fails

TEST

```
/// <summary>
/// Tests the dot product from the layer
/// </summary>
/// <param name=""></param>
/// <param name=""></param>
TEST(Perception_Test, Test_Layer_Prediction_without_bias) {
    Neural_Node node1(1);
    Neural_Node node2(2);
    Neural_Node node3(3);
    Neural_Node node4(4);

    Weight weight1(1);
    Weight weight2(2);
    Weight weight3(3);
    Weight weight4(4);

    Prediction prediction30(30);

    Layer test_layer(4);


    vector<vector<Neural_Node>> test_inputs = { 
        { node1, node2, node3, node4 },
        { node1, node2, node3, node4 },
        { node1, node2, node3, node4 },
        { node1, node2, node3, node4 }
    };

    vector<vector<Weight>> test_weights = {
        {weight1,weight2,weight3,weight4},
        {weight1,weight2,weight3,weight4},
        {weight1,weight2,weight3,weight4},
        {weight1,weight2,weight3,weight4}
    };

    vector<vector<Prediction>> comparison = { 
        {prediction30, prediction30, prediction30, prediction30},
        {prediction30, prediction30, prediction30, prediction30},
        {prediction30, prediction30, prediction30, prediction30},
        {prediction30, prediction30, prediction30, prediction30}
    };

    test_layer.Dot_Product(test_inputs, test_weights);
    
    vector<vector<Prediction>> prediction_without_bias =
                         test_layer.Get_Prediction_Without_Bias();

    bool b = (prediction_without_bias == comparison);
     
    //EXPECT_TRUE();
}
```

Weight, Prediction, and Neural_Node are all children classes of Perception_Element

I can successfully compare 1 prediction to another

But when it's buried in a vector of vectors it fails

ERROR:

> Error C2672   'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded
> function found

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the full error message? You've only posted the error summary. If you're using Visual Studio, then the full error message is in the `Output` pane. The full error message does NOT appear in the `Error` pane.

Comment: I think @Retired Ninja was right -- I changed my == operator to value == element.value and it seems to work now If someone can tell me how to flag a answer as correct i think i have it now

Comment: Green checkmark under the voting arrows to the left of the answer

Comment: Please don't edit a question in such a way that it invalidates answers to it. When you receive an answer to your question, leave the question as is and mark the answer accepted. Editing your question to include the new code just makes things confusing.

Comment: I have rolled this question back to the last good version.

Answer (score 3):

When I copy your code into gcc, and then make hundreds of lines of changes, I get the error message:

```
main.cpp:103:39:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:1161:29: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'const Perception::Layer::Element::Prediction' and 'const Perception::Layer::Element::Prediction')
 1161 |             if (!(*__first1 == *__first2))
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:45:6: note: candidate: 'bool Perception::Layer::Element::Perception_Element::operator==(Perception::Layer::Element::Perception_Element)' (near match)
   45 | bool Perception_Element::operator==(const Perception_Element element) {
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:45:6: note:   passing 'const Perception::Layer::Element::Prediction*' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers
```

The problem is that your `operator==` method isn't `const`, and so cannot be called by non-mutating algorithms, like vector's `operator==`.

The correct signature is:

```
bool operator==(const Perception& element) const
                ^^^^^           ^          ^^^^^
```